# How to add days this countdown script so that it becomes DD-HH-MM-SS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I have this script in jQuery:

```
// Auction countdown script
$(function () {

var remaining = $("#countdown").text(),
    regex = /\d{2}/g,
    matches = remaining.match(regex),
    hours = matches[0],
    minutes = matches[1],
    seconds = matches[2],
    remainingDate = new Date();

remainingDate.setHours(hours);
remainingDate.setMinutes(minutes);
remainingDate.setSeconds(seconds);

var intvl = setInterval(function () {
    var totalMs = remainingDate.getTime(),
        hours, minutes, seconds;

remainingDate.setTime(totalMs - 1000);

hours = remainingDate.getHours();
minutes = remainingDate.getMinutes();
seconds = remainingDate.getSeconds();

if (hours === 0 && minutes === 0 && seconds === 0) {
    alert('done');
}

$("#countdown").text(
    (hours >= 10 ? hours : "0" + hours) + ":" +
    (minutes >= 10 ? minutes : "0" + minutes)  + ":" +
    (seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0" + seconds));

}, 1000);

});
```

Now, this takes a string and makes a HHMMSS countdown for it. I want it to be DDHHMMSS but I can't seem to get it to work. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using one of the many existing jquery countdown plugins such as http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html?

Answer (score 3):

If you like to create countdown function by yourself then Please take reference from below links to build right logic :

#### http://stuntsnippets.com/javascript-countdown/

#### http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm

OR

its better to use one of below **jQuery plugin**

#### http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/

#### http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Hope it helps

#### ALL D BEST

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that Date objects are for dates and times, not time intervals. So setDate() and getDate() operate on the date of the month, not a count of days.

You could simply use integers and divide by the number of seconds in a minute, minutes in an hour, etc. Or you could implement a TimeInterval object, as described here:

http://i-programmer.info/programming/javascript/3088-a-javascript-timeinterval-object.html

Answer (score -1):

Use `toString` for that:

```
var remainingDate = new Date();
remainingDate.toString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

This returns for example `01-08-2012 14:08:22`